# Display only image using this widget

Tags: javascript, twitter

I'm using this script, but it displays many things around it. I just want to show the image, nothing else. How can I do that?

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" data-dnt="true" 
href="https://twitter.com/hashtag/photogridly" data-widget-id="700623712718970884" 
data-chrome="nofooter noborders">#photogridly Tweets</a> <script>
!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';
if(!d.getElementById(id))
{js=d.createElement(s);
js.id=id;js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
```

Comment: I think it would be better if you can add your code in JSfiddle so that people can edit and get it working for you

Comment: This code generates an iframe holding a specific tweet. If you want to get the media from a tweet I suggest reading up on the API twitter provides and use that to get the media from tweets.